# Reparametrization by arc length

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

I am having problems to interpret the problem 1.12 from Do Carmo Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces. The problem says:
"Let $\alpha: I \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a regular parametrized curve (not necessarily by arc length) and let $\beta:J \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a reparametrization of $\alpha(I)$ by the arc length $s=s(t)$, measured from $t_0 \in I$. Let $t = t(s)$ be the inverse function of $s$. Prove: $\tfrac{dt}{ds} = \tfrac{1}{|{\alpha'}|}$.

How should $\beta$ be defined here? I think the correct interpretation is $\beta(s) = \alpha(t(s))$ so $\beta = \alpha \circ t$. With this interpretation we get:

$$ \beta'(s) = \alpha'(t(s)) t'(s) $$
so taking norms and using $\beta$ is parametrized by arc length:
$$ 1 = |\alpha'(t(s))| t'(s) $$
and by the inverse function theorem:
$$ t'(s) = \tfrac{1}{|\alpha'(t(s))|}$$
which is the result we are looking for. However, I would expect that the correct form for the reparametrization is $\beta = \alpha \circ s$? How should this be interpreted, as $\beta = \alpha \circ t$ or $\beta = \alpha \circ s$?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of this question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3981346/how-to-rigorously-define-the-parametric-derivative

Comment: @Buraian I disagree this is a duplicate and that question doesn’t even have an answer

Comment: Your argument says which is correct; the issue is therefore to resolve your intuition that things should be otherwise. It may help to draw a picture of the intervals $I$ and $J$ and the maps between them, or to note that if $s = \sigma(t)$ (introducing a new symbol to avoid overloading), then $\sigma^{-1}:J \to I$ (a.k.a. $t$) takes arclengths as inputs and returns parameter values for $\alpha$ as outputs, or some such.