# Formal definition of virtual displacement

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

I'm trying to read a book on classical mechanics, and I'm having a hard time trying to know what exactly is a virtual displacement, sometimes called a variation. In the Lagrangian "formalism" the differential forms $dx$ are changed by "virtual displacements" and noted by $\delta x$. As far as I understand the unique difference between $dx$ and $\delta x$ is that $\delta x$ doesn't depends on time, that is, $\delta x$ is a purely spatial differential form.

However in a book of classical mechanics I see that $\delta \dot q$ can be "integrated" respect to $dt$ to give $\delta q$, what makes no sense if $\delta q$ will be a differential form. So, I would like to know a precise and very formal definition of some expression like $\delta x$. I tried to find such formal (mathematically rigorous) definition in many books of mechanics or differential geometry but I could not find one, so I would appreciate some reference or explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer that fit my doubts. If we have a manifold $M\times \mathbb{R}$ and a coordinate system $\varphi :=(q_1(t),\ldots ,q_n(t),\dot q_1(t),\ldots ,\dot q_n(t),t)$ then we can set $\delta p:=i^*dp$ where $i:M\times \{t_0\}\to M\times \mathbb{R}$ for every coordinate $p$. This is what I assumed from first place. However in a book I see written something like

$$
\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q_k}\delta \dot q_k\,d t=-\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\delta q_k \frac{d}{d t}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q_k}\right)\,d t\tag1
$$

This confused me a lot, however if we think as $\delta p$ as above then we dont need to introduce an extraneous $d t$ in the integral, because we will have $\delta \dot q=\ddot q\,d t$ and we just can write
$$
\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q_k}\delta \dot q_k=-\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\frac{d}{d t}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q_k}\right)\delta q_k\tag2
$$

assuming that the $dt$ in the expression $\delta \dot q=\ddot q\,d t$ is the differential form on the cotangent bundle in the domain of $\psi :\mathbb{R}\to M\times \{t_0\}$, where $\psi :=(q_1(t),\ldots ,q_n(t),\dot q_1(t),\ldots ,\dot q_n(t),t_0)$. By now this is the best theoretical setting that I've found to understand the notion of "virtual displacement" given in books of classical dynamics.

This is almost the same idea shown [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/456824/328248).

Answer (score 2):

Assume that the functional (a function/map/operator that has a function as input and a number as output) is given as
$$F[ρ]=\int_\Omega f\Bigl(x,ρ(x),∇ρ(x)\Bigr)\,dx.$$

For the variation in directional-derivative form you then get
\begin{align}
δF[ρ;ψ]&=\lim_{s\to0}\frac{F[ρ+sψ]-F[ρ]}{s}
\\[.3em]&=\int_\Omega \left[ \frac{∂f}{∂ρ}\Bigl(x,ρ(x),\nabla ρ(x)\Bigr)ψ(x)+\frac{∂f}{∂∇ρ}\Bigl(x,ρ(x),\nabla ρ(x)\Bigr)∇ψ(x)\right]\,dx.
\end{align}
Here $∂ρ$ and $∂∇ρ$ in the partial-derivative symbol just indicate the place in the arguments of $f$ that the partial derivative is taken for, there is no other special magic involved. If one writes $f(x,y,v)$ as the "canonical" arguments of $f$, the partial derivatives could also be written as $\frac{∂f}{∂y}$ and $\frac{∂f}{∂v}$.

One could use $δρ$ as function symbol instead of $ψ$, in a slight abuse of notation $∇δρ$ might then be written as $δ∇ρ$. Or you might declare $δρ(x)[ψ]=ψ(x)$ as the evaluation operator for the derivative direction function $ψ$.

The variation in differential-quotient form $\frac{δF[ρ]}{δρ(x)}$ can now be defined as some limit over the support of $ψ$ shrinking to the point $x$, or more systematically over the demand that
$$
δF[ρ;ψ]=\int_\Omega \frac{δF[ρ]}{δρ(x)}δρ(x)[ψ]\,dx+\int_{∂\Omega}...
$$
To that end one would have to get rid of the derivative terms $∇ψ$. That is achieved using some variation of the fundamental theorem of calculus, generally called Stokes theorem for differential forms (Greene, Gauss,...). This gives in interior points
$$
\frac{δF}{δρ(x)}[ρ]=\frac{∂f}{∂ρ}\Bigl(x,ρ(x),\nabla ρ(x)\Bigr)-∇^*\frac{∂f}{∂∇ρ}\Bigl(x,ρ(x),\nabla ρ(x)\Bigr).
$$

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the definition of the [functional differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative). To complement the explanation from Wikipedia, you can also have a look at the answer I provided for [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3981346/how-to-rigorously-define-the-parametric-derivative/4403490#4403490) somewhat simpler question.

To summarize the key idea, consider the total derivative for an $n$-dimensional vector space (or a function with $n$ inputs)
$$
df(x, h) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} h_i \Rightarrow
df(x, h) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} dx_i(x, h)
\textit{, for $dx_i(x, h) = h_i$}
$$
and then take the same idea and map it to functionals (functions that take a function as input) to get
$$
\delta f[\rho,\psi] = \int \frac{\delta f}{\delta \rho}(x) \psi(x) dx \Rightarrow
\delta f[\rho,\psi] = \int \frac{\delta f}{\delta \rho}(x) \delta\rho(x) dx 
\textit{, for $\delta\rho[\rho, \psi](x) = \psi(x)$}
$$